# AmazonCloudFormation CDK ERROR on AWS Code Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I'm getting the error below after running the pipepline

> Unable to fetch parameters [/cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version] from parameter store for this account. (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 9bc784ac-193c-4dbe-97c0-4ecb90ce4c2d; Proxy: null)

I'm trying to setup CI/CD via code commit, code deploy, and pipeline. I added another stage in the pipleline for cloudformation but I'm getting this error when I try to run the pipeline.

Source and Build stage Succeeds but it fails on deploy stage.

[image: build failure]